# Is it okay to use wider trace than actually required while designing a PCB?

Tags: pcb, current, pcb-design, eaglecad, trace

I used eagle to recently, design a board with all trace widths 30 mills except a few as 20 mills. I actually didn't require traces this wide and 15 mills would probably have been enough. Does this cause any sort of issues in the functioning of the board?

Answer (score 2):

the thicker the trace the better but most times you do not have the luxury to have such thick traces. The thinner the trace the harder to manufacture and the cost can increase if you go too thin. A safe lower end is 7 mil for a regular thickness board (1oz copper)

Comment: I think today 4mil on inner layer is fine. 5milmis fine on outer layer.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum 5 mil would disqualify you from all of the cheap Chinese manufacturers, OSH Park, and pretty much everything else common for hobbyists. They all have a 6 mil limit.

Comment: I am not sure how important this is to find the exact chinese specs, but i produce 5mil boards for the last five-six years in china, some i even order online. Actually vias are more challenging, suddenly chinese guys propose such  tolerance that you never know if the annular ring remains.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on application. For analog circuit you reduce resistance and inductance of the trace, while capacitance is increased. Generally it's probably better, but not always. For digital circuits it's common to set characteristic impedance to 50Ohm cand calculate trace width accordingly (board stackup matters!). Usually you don't get numbers higher than 8mil.

Upd: when i say capacitance, i mean two separate cases: capacity to ground planes- that one is calculatable and is under your control, and to all other stuff around, including things outside the board. That one is usually quite small, but completely out of control. So too wide trace may sometimes lead to interference getting in through capacitance.

Comment: +1, but when you say "capacity" I think you mean "capacitance".

Comment: Believe me, this the autocorrect, not me!

Answer (score 2):

There are fundamental reasons for traces being a certain width, whether you use 1 oz or 2 oz copper, and how many layers you have. For me it depended on whether the trace was for power, ground or data. Also I was in touch with the board house often to discuss minimum trace widths and minimum slot widths (to prevent crepage between high voltage or high impedance traces, often 31 mils was the limit). Given those guidelines I used the following loose rules:

1) Ground traces were more like copper pours in that they covered broad areas of the board. Ground pours in RF areas had a diamond shaped pattern (no copper for 50 mils) to break up standing waves. Analog and digital grounds were *always* separate until they met at the power connector or an ADC, which was the end-point for the analog signals. Analog traces crossed over digital traces at right angles to avoid analog noise.

2) Power traces were 30 mils wide but 50 to 100 mils wide if they had to carry several amps of current.

3) Data traces were 20 mils wide and 3 mils wide/3 mils spacing for LVDS which had a dedicated ground trace under it that was 10 mils wide. Also LVDS and RF required that corners be 45 degree turns with a outer cut that was 1.6 times the trace width.

4) There is no single width that fits all applications. You cannot say that less copper makes for a cheaper board because boards start out as 4 foot by 8 foot sheets with copper on one or both sides. Different stacks had 1 oz and 2 oz copper sheets. You are paying the board house to etch away unwanted copper after they drill all the holes first and cut all the required slots, if any.

5) What cost extra is slot cuts, multi-layer boards, and gold flash for boards that use RoHS compatible solder. They charge for vias and holes as well, so overall a SMD is much cheaper to make than a thru-hole board that does the same thing. Through-holes are mostly for connectors and large parts. Many of today's IC's have a high pin density where 20 mil wide traces may have to narrow to 5 mils for IC's with 0.4mm pin centers. Most thru-holes on SMD boards are for via's.

6) Outside of having as much ground pour as possible, it is often the parts, current flow and signal speed that determine trace width. Lacking any special needs 30 mil wide traces are fine. If possible look at mother boards for computers up close and you will see why certain traces are 'fat' while others may be 3 mils wide, and in pairs.

Comment: RE: "less copper makes a cheaper board", I've actually heard it the other way around --- less etched area causes the etchant bath to last longer and so makes a cheaper board. I doubt this effect is relevant for runs less than 1,000 panels though.

Comment: @ThePhoton. Granted. The small runs were to fit full panels at the board house to keep cost down. 15 boards for ATE fixtures was not going to have a low price. It takes thousands of boards over years for pricing to turn a profit.